# Mongoose Replicaset Connection Not Working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to connect to AWS MongoDB instances and its not even attempting to connect:

This is the connection URI:

```
mongodb://<usr>:<pwd>@host:port,host2:port2/db
```

And this is the code I am using to connect.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var dbOptions = { server: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 300000, connectTimeoutMS: 30000 } }, 
            replset: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 300000, connectTimeoutMS : 30000 } } };

mongoose.connect(uri, dbOptions);
```

I also added logs inside events.. none of the events are firing. If I remove `host2:port2` it works. So issue seems to be with the connection string. But connection string looks totally fine.. but still its not working.. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried adding an error callback to the connection line? e.g. mongoose.connect(uri, dbOptions, function(err) { if(err) console.log('Connection error: ' + err); } ) . Also, you may want to try adding the replicaSet parameter to the connection string: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/connection-string/#uri.replicaSet

Comment: @AdamHarrison getting nothing there.